# SetStyleSheet not working in qt

Tags: qt

```
void PriceChecker::setBaseUrl()
{
   QInputDialog dlg;
    dlg.setStyleSheet("background-color:black");
    QString baseUrl = dlg.getText(m_pMainWidget, "Settings", "Enter BaseURL");
    if (!baseUrl.isEmpty())
    {
        m_settings.setValue("baseurl", baseUrl);
        m_settings.sync();
    }
}
```

The dlg has always same color as its parent widget. I tried to change only the color of lineedit by

```
myDialog->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background-color: yellow }");@
```

Also I tried

```
 qApp->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background-color: yellow }");@
```

any of this didin't work.

Answer (score 1):

QDialogs are a bit restricted in css properties applicable to them.

As stated in [QDialog css properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties)

> Supports only the background, background-clip and background-origin
>   properties.

Answer (score -2):

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background-color: yellow ;};");

 }  between )      ";"  input?
```